# .NETCore 3.0 not listed as TargetFramework in VS2019

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I installed the NetCore 3.0 RTM SDK (x64), but I'm unable to target it in VisualStudio 2019 (16.2.5).

Here are the versions of Runtimes and SDKs I have installed:

```
C:\Users\pauls>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

C:\Users\pauls>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.202 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.505 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.700 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.701 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.801 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.802 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.301 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Here is what I get in Visual Studio.
[image: VS Target Framework selector]

My PATH variable includes `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` and `C:\Users\pauls\.dotnet\tools`.  I've also repaired the installation and rebooted but no joy.  The target framework selection excludes core 3.0 for both new projects and existing projects.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only VisualStudio 2019 16.3.x supports Core 3.0.

Update your VS 2019 and try again.

Comment: Doh!  I usually rely on the VS notifications tray to tell me when new updates are available and it didn't show anything.  Manually checking did the trick, thanks @Richard

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling with this issue for more than I would like to admit.